# Прокомментируйте решение задачи с acm.timus. В чём ошибка?

Tags: c++

> Обратный корень
> Ограничение времени: 2.0 секунды
> Ограничение памяти: 16 МБ
>
> Исходные данные
> Входной поток содержит набор целых чисел Ai (0 ≤ Ai ≤ 1018), отделённых друг от друга произвольным количеством пробелов и переводов строк. Размер входного потока не превышает 256 КБ.
>
> Результат
> Для каждого числа Ai, начиная с последнего и заканчивая первым, в отдельной строке вывести его квадратный корень не менее чем с четырьмя знаками после десятичной точки.

[Задача](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001).

Я её решил так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

void sqrt_f(double n)
{
    printf ( "%.4f\n", sqrt( static_cast<double>( n ) ) );
}

int main()
{
    std::list<double> numbers;
    std::string sInput;
    getline( std::cin, sInput );
    std::istringstream parse( sInput );
    double tmp;
    while ( parse >> tmp )
        numbers.push_front( tmp );
    std::for_each(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sqrt_f);
    return 0;
}
```

При проверке выдаётся Wrong answer. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Считать все числа (игнорируя все пробелы, переводы строк, табуляции и т.д.) можно с помощью scanf(). Например так:

```
while (scanf("%d", &x) != EOF)  //дошли ли до конца?
{
   //считали целое в x теперь работаем с ним
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Вместо "sqrt_f" можно использовать функтор, это может ускорить вызов

2) Можно попробовать читать через istreambuf_iterator (подробнее в "Эффективном использовании STL")

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй

```
void sqrt_f(double n)
```

Заменить на

```
void sqrt_f(unsigned double n)
```

Comment: timus1001.cpp:10: error: ‘signed’ or ‘unsigned’ invalid for ‘n’

Comment: Это какой компилятор такую ошибку выдает?

Comment: да

Answer (score 0):

В порядке вывода результата. Вот Вам и `push_front` с последующим `for_each`

**upd**
после уяснения условий задачи:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<double> numbers;
    list<double>::iterator it;
    while (1) {
    double tmp;
        cin >> tmp;
        if(cin.eof()) break;
    numbers.push_front( sqrt(tmp) );
    }
    cout.precision(4);
    cout.setf(ios::fixed, ios::floatfield);
    for (it=numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: дак в обратном же порядке надо вывести. push_front кладёт новый элемент всегда в начало. Т.е. последнее входное число - будет первым. И потом я применяю for_each. По-моему не в этом проблема или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Это я невнимательно прочитал условие задачи. Пришлось перечитывать. За что меня так? В условиях написано "отделённых друг от друга произвольным количеством пробелов и переводов строк". Ваша `getline` прочитает только первую стоку.

Comment: "За что меня так? " - это Вы к чему? 
А как прочитать тогда и переводы строк? можете подсказать?